# How to Make Tabs In CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make tabs contents using CSS. I have already made my custom tab style but I can't make its content with CSS. Can anyone tell me how I can do that ?

**CSS:**

```
.tabs {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tabs li:not(.active):hover
{
    background: #ccc;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.tabs li > a
{   
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray
}
.tabs li.active
{
    z-index: 1000;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    color: grey;
    cursor: default;
}
.tabs:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.tabs:before
{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab3">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4X8km/)

Comment: You would typically mix in some JS with this. Most JS UI libraries have built-in tab controls already. perhaps consider one of those (jQuery UI would be a good place to start)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+tabs

Comment: Are there any restictions considering the use of JavaScript? Does it have to be CSS-only?

Comment: I Dont Want To Use Javascript Only CSS.

Comment: Downvoted. Just did a quick Google search for the words "css tabs" and there are way too many answers there to justify this question. Do your research

Comment: [Creating content tabs with pure CSS](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/)

Comment: Downvoted in favor of the mighty Google + question is vague at best.

Comment: Here's a real simple jQuery tab example - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/mapW2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way to implement a "pure **CSS**" *tab control*. From this [example](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/), I've modified the HTML part of your [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cd3Bk/) to add `<div>` content within `<li>` markup. I then added those two bits of styling to acually hide inactive tabs.

```
/* Content specific css for tabs*/
.tabs li div {
    display: none;
}

/* Content specific css for the active tab */
.tabs li.active div {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}
```

I then **[changed](http://jsfiddle.net/jbvQ4/1/)** your idea of having `<a>` as header links, as those wouldn't carry a state in "pure **CSS**". I removed your `.active` rendered useless by using radio inputs (to force only one active tab at a time). The only broken repercussion from this change is on the active `tab`'s content **CSS** selector. Instead of the previous : `.tabs li.active div`, it's now the following :

```
.tabs input[name=tabs]:checked ~ div
```

That is translated to : select `divs` with a sibling `input` tag `named` `tabs` that is *checked*.

You were actually pretty close with your implementation, your main error can be explained by neglecting the following statement : **Preserving a state in pure CSS requires radio or checkbox inputs**.

Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is what u want

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #5E6EBF;
}
.tab-menu {
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 0 76px;
}
.tabs {
 width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 45px;
}
.tab-content {
 display: none;
}
.tabs input {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0;
}
.tabs label {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 40px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tab-content p {
 line-height: 29px;
 font-style: italic;
}
.tabs input:checked + label {
 background-color: #4B5898;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.tabs input:checked ~ .tab-content {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 65px;
 width: 1200px;
 padding: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 76px;
 background-color: #4B5898;
 color: #ffffff;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1300px){
 .tabs input:checked ~ .tab-content {
 max-width: 800px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
 .tabs input:checked ~ .tab-content {
 max-width: 500px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px){
 .tab-menu {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.tabs input:checked ~ .tab-content {
 left: 10px;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 525px){
 .tabs {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
 }
 .tabs input:checked ~ .tab-content {
 left: 10px;
 top: 60px;
 max-width: 270px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="tab-menu">
   <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="myradio" checked>
     <label>TAB1</label>
    </input>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <h3>One Content</h3>
     <p>Is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publ</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="myradio">
     <label>TAB2</label>
    </input>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <h3>Two Content</h3>
     <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage,</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="myradio">
     <label>TAB3</label>
    </input>
    <div class="tab-content">
     <h3>Three Content</h3>
     <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form,</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/zMNZWv